# How to fix: "anonymous function bodies must be single expressions" error on Octave

Tags: octave, anonymous-function

I am trying to make a function in Octave where you give octave a function f(x,y) as a string, a change in X, a change in Y, a starting point, and the size of a matrix, the function will create a matrix populated with the values of f(x,y) at each point in the matrix.

This is for an application that displays a 3d graph, using the matrix to map each value to a block

```
# funcStr: The function whose Z values are being calculated
# dx: the change in x that each block in the x direction represents
# dy: the change in y that each block in the y direction represents
# startPt: the point (in an array of x, y) that center block represents
# res: the side length (in blocks) of the plane

pkg load symbolic
syms x y
function[zValues] = calculateZValues(funcStr, dx, dy, startPt, res)

zValues = zeros(res);
eqn = @(x, y) inline(funcStr);

startX = startPt{1};
startY = startPt{2};

for yOffset = 1:res
    for xOffset = 1:res
        xCoord = startX + dx * xOffset;
        yCoord = startY + dy * yOffset;
        zValues(res * yOffset + xOffset) = double(subs(eqn, @(x, y), {xCoord, yCoord}));
    endfor
endfor
endfunction
```

The error I am getting is:

```
>> calculateZValues("x*y", 1, 1, {0,0}, 10)
parse error near line 20 of file /home/rahul/Documents/3dGraph/graph/calculateZValues.m

  anonymous function bodies must be single expressions

>>>             zValues(res * yOffset + xOffset) = double(subs(eqn, @(x, y), {xCoord, yCoord}));
```

I have no idea what the issue is. I have replaced the @(x,y) part with {x,y} in the line referenced by the error but it says nothing or it raises an error about the function `subs` not being declared. I have also tried moving the `pkg` and `syms` lines above the function header

Comment: ` @(x, y)` is the 2nd of 3 arguments there. But it’s an incomplete function definition. It has no body. Is to fix this error depends wholly on what you were trying to do with that line of code. I can’t guess at that.

Comment: From what I understand, `subs` is a function included in the symbolic pkg library that substitutes numbers for variables, and double evaluates the function. I'm trying to call `subs`

Comment: I think you are confusing anonymous functions and symbolic functions. You are putting function handle `eqn` into `subs`, instead of a symbolic expression. Read the examples [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) to learn how to use symbolic substitution.